# MySQL query performance for paginating

Tags: mysql

Ok, so what is the best practice when it comes down to paginating in mysql. Let me make it more clear, let's say that a given time I have 2000 records and there are more being inserted. And I am displaying 25 at a time, I know I have to use limit to paginate through the records. But what am I supposed to do for the total count of my records? Do I count the records every time users click to request the next 25 records. Please, don't tell me the answer straight up but rather point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to just continue working with the result set normally as new records are inserted.  Presumably, each page you display will use a query looking something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY someCol
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 100
```

As the user pages back and forth, if new data were to come in it is possible that a page could change from what it was previously.  From a logical point of view, this isn't so bad.  For example, if you had an alphabetical list of products and a new product appeared, then the user would receive this information in a fairly nice way.

As for counting, your code can allow moving to the next page so long as data is there to support a new page being added.  Having new records added might mean more pages required to cover the entire table, but it should not affect your logic used to determine when to stop allowing pages.

If your table has a date or timestamp column representing when a record was added, then you might actually be able to restrict the entire result set to a snapshot in time.  In this case, you could prevent new data from entering over a given session.

Comment: Thanks! But I am more concerned about the performance. Should I be reading every time? How the big companies do it. I don't think they count every time users move to the next page!

Comment: @Jonathan You don't even need to count AFAIK.  Just choose a page size and try querying.  When you get nothing back, you know you have exceeded the size of the table.  Anyway, as you pointed out, the size of the table is ever changing.

Comment: That's true, but how do I show users how may pages they are looking at?

Comment: For this you could do a count query, but you might only need to do it initially.

Answer (score 0):

3 sugggestions
1. Only refreshing the data grid, while clicking the next button via ajax (or) storing the count in session for the search parameters opted .
2. Using memcache which is advanced, can be shared across all the users. Generate a unique key based on the filter parameters and keep the count. So you won't hit the data base. When a new record, gets added then you need to clear the existing memcache key. This requires a memache to be running. 
3. Create a indexing and if you hit the db for getting the count alone. There won't be much any impact on performance.